# Having a literal "@" in TexMaker user commands

Tags: texmaker, preamble

I am wanting to make a user command that serves as a one-click preamble.

```
\documentclass[answers,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.in]{geometry}
\input{mystyle.sty}

\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{exam}{
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathdots}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{SolutionColor}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,1}

\unframedsolutions
\shadedsolutions
\definecolor{SolutionColor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,1}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\textbf{Solution: }}
}{
\newtheoremstyle{sol}
{3pt}
{3pt}
{}
{}
{\bfseries}
{:}
{.5em}
{}
\theoremstyle{sol}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
}
\makeatother
```

Above is that preamble. However, since "@" is the texmaker syntax for a wildcard, it defaults to that. I was wondering if there was a way to write a literal @ that will not be treated like a wildcard.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I can't help with texmaker,but why use `\@ifclassloaded` in the preamble? The case you  show the test is always false, as you load article and test for exam, so it just makes the preamble larger and slower to execute?  You could just add the test block without `\makeatletter` to the end of `\mystyle.sty` so all you would need then is `\input{mystyle.sty}` or to write it in more idiomatic latex, `\usepackage{mystyle}`

Comment: if you used the intended command,  `\usepackage` , instead of `\input` then you would not need `\makeat...`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the pointer, that made it look a lot nicer!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you post that comment as an answer, I will accept it, since it solves my original issue along with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case you show the test is always false, as you load article and test for exam, so it just makes the preamble larger and slower to execute?

You could just add the test block without `\makeatletter` to the end of `mystyle.sty` so all you would need then is `\input{mystyle.sty}` or to write it in more idiomatic latex, `\usepackage{mystyle}`